# post rel value by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security

I use `rel=""` to pass value to insert page like this:

**Html** code

```
<p>post 1</p> 
<a href="" rel="<? echo $id_post; ?>">Like</a>
<br />
<p>post 2</p> 
<a href="" rel="<? echo $id_post; ?>">Like</a>
<br />
<p>post 3</p> 
<a href="" rel="<? echo $id_post; ?>">Like</a>
```

I get rel value like this by jquery:

```
$(a).click(function(){
var rel = $(this) .attr('rel');
});
```

In submit page I have this:

```
<?
//here is the value
$post_id = $_POST['rel'];
?>
```

But anybody can change `rel` value in Google chrome. How can I make it safe?

Comment: may b by doing extra checks on Server side against the POST'ed rel value..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the rel value to the click event handler when you create it, so that it doesn't actually get it at the time of the click...

```
$("a.like-link").each(function() {
    var rel = this.rel;
    $(this).on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(rel);
    });
});
```

**[jsfiddle example...](http://jsfiddle.net/asNRJ/)**

You should be aware though, that this will not stop people being able to send whatever they want to your server.  Anyone that would be "in the know" enough to be able to see in your code that you're using the rel value in a post would also know enough to turn off your click handler and add their own.  There is *nothing* you can do to stop people making changes client-side.  You can just make it more of a hassle for a would-be hacker.

Answer (score 0):

**Never, Never, and Never trust to Client Side**! You can do some modifications, of course, do some jobs from client side, but at the end any other normal developer can change this too.
You can encrypt flash data by salt and md5, attacker can see requested data, it would be encrypted, but still be able to modified.

Always check your Ajax requests from Server, do some security codes with Javascript, but check it in PHP too. If you send some kind of information that depends on user, check with session in PHP ...

> Remember, that you always have possibilities to check and protect requests in
>   server side. You only need correct system arcitecture.

Always use **POST** method. This way you block direct access to server file.

If user wants to click on the 1st post like button and change the buttons rel to 2, he/she would rate the second article automatically and you cannot avoid it. You can avoid rating articles, that do not exist in database and check SQL and other errors, respectively.

On the other hand, for now, this kind of habit is not considered to be hacking, if user changes some kind of code from browser that affects only his/her information (except balance and such things, that may be checked from PHP easily). 
Imagine that source file is the same thing as browser shows beautifully. So let him/her do what they want to do, you must protect other users data, your system, database and so on.

> **And one of the most important thing, Never send user session and user data from Javascript, always use SESSIONS**